# add ID number to the feather m0 bootloader (flash)

Tags: bootloader, adafruit, samd21g

I'm trying to add a serial number to the bootloader's flash area of Adafruit Feather m0 board. Seems like feather m0 0-0x2000 area on the flash is non writable by the arduino sketch. i wanted to add a serial number to address 0x2000 - 8 on the flash. 
The idea is for the data to be included in the bootloader elf\bin so i can easily flash it on devices and later on access it using flash address  (0x2000 - 8) with NVMCTRL.

I've started out with this solution:

downloaded the code from [samd21 arduino bootloader github directory](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-samd) and in ./bootloaders/zero edited the boololoader ld script, first the "Memory" section

```
FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x2000 /* First 8KB used by bootloader */
FLASHID (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00002000 - 0x0008, LENGTH = 8
```

Then the 'sections' section:

```
.id_sec :
  {
    KEEP(*(.myid))
  } > FLASHID
```

This should have saved some room in the end of the flash for the id. now in the main.c file:

```
__attribute__ ((section(".myid"))) const unsigned long ID = 0xdead1234;
```

Which should have saved the 0xdead1234 hex value in the (0x2000-8) address.

The issue is this:
I compiled this code and linked it just fine, got .hex,.bin,.elf files.
If i'm correct (unless they are somehow compressed) i should be able to see the code 0xdead in the binary. 
**BUT** i don't. 
After objdump on the binary(any of them) i can't find the 0xde 0xad in any order anywhere.
The `arm-none-eabi-size" --format=sysv -t -x build/.elf` does not show the new section i added no where.
Also i do wonder, as i said the 0x2000 address on the flash is non writable once i flashed with atmel-ice \j-link even the bootloader code cannot write to it, i did define in the ld script that i want that memory region part of the flash so i do expect that the compiler + linker + jlink flasher will know to write that data to the right place but not sure.

Anyone got some experience with it ? did it before ?

Comment: instead of 0xde 0xad, look for 0xed 0xda ... maybe it is stored in little endian

Comment: Your question is amazingly hard to read. See [How to ask a good question](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2523/how-to-ask-a-good-question-for-arduino-stack-exchange). Take a bit of time to make some paragraphs, spell "I" with a capital "I", and generally explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: @jsotola i did try that, well aware of the endianess. i basically tried just to use objdump and xxd and then grep it twice once for 'ed' and once for 'da' which should capture all possibilities.

Comment: Hi @NickGammon sorry , i see what u are talking about some parts slipped in from stackoverflow, i posted there too and copy-paste it and it needs some fixing, but in general i explain exactly what i wanted to achieve and what i did to achieve it, i was asking what can i do actually get it done.

Comment: Hey @NickGammon changed the question a bit i hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Cross-posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50113720/). The question looks better, however see See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/) - you have to decide which site you want to ask on. Stack Exchange does not want you to ask your question over multiple of its sites.

Comment: Can understand them, though i think at times it's unjust as the question does fit nicely to any of them, stackoverflow is more generic and this is indeed a programming question, however it is in need of someone that also flashed a boot-loader or did a  certain procedure for embedded devices  in the past. which i guess i'll see mostly here.
In any case deleted it from stackoverflow and will repost if i don't get any answer here.

Comment: You know the samd21 already has a unique serial number [that you can access](https://gist.github.com/mgk/c9ec87436d2d679e5d08).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite an easy fix, actually.

The problem here is the compiler doesn't think the const is used for anything - so it (quite rightly) throws it away.

All you need to do is tell the compiler that it's `used` and all should be good:

```
__attribute__((section(".myid"),used)) const unsigned long ID = 0xdead1234;
```

And when you compile:

```
build/.elf  :
section             size         addr
.vectors            0x40          0x0
.text             0x18d4         0x40
.data               0x5c   0x20000000
.bss               0x34c   0x2000005c
.id_sec              0x4       0x1ff8
.ARM.attributes     0x28          0x0
.comment            0x80          0x0
.debug_frame        0x68          0x0
Total             0x1dd0
```

Properly, though, you should make some more changes to the linker script to properly isolate those 8 bytes of flash (though you don't *have* to).

1. You should reduce `FLASH` by 8 bytes.
2. You should include the FLASHID length in the `__sketch_vectors_ptr` calculation.

That's:

```
MEMORY
{
  FLASH   (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x1FF8 /* First 8KB used by bootloader */
  FLASHID (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00001FF8, LENGTH = 8
  RAM    (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x00008000-0x0004 /* 4 bytes used by bootloader to keep data between resets */
}
```

And:

```
PROVIDE(__sketch_vectors_ptr = ORIGIN(FLASH) + LENGTH(FLASH) + LENGTH(FLASHID));
```

That way the compiled bootloader code can never be placed in the FLASHID area (not that it would at the moment, but if a new version of the bootloader were released that used 100% of the lower block of flash it would conflict).

Of course, if all you need is something unique to identify the board with, all AVR and SAMD devices that have built-in USB support have a unique ID number. This is intended to be used as the Serial Number for the USB, but could also be used for a MAC address for Ethernet (or for portions of it anyway) or other unique "node" addresses.

Comment: thanks! checking myself, if indeed i can see it i'll mark as the solution

Comment: @codeScriber note first the comment that the chip already has a unique ID.  Next, if you want to serialize like this, after setting a default from the compiler, in practice you'd probably want to directly overwrite the values in the binary to be flashed (`dd` or many other tools can write at an offset) rather than recompile for each unit.

Comment: I do something similar to set a unique USERID value on PIC32 chips when programming a bootloader from a HEX file. Allocate it from a database, then filter the HEX file changing the values that need changing and recalculating the checksums.

Comment: @ChrisStratton  thanks that's exactly what i planned to do though i planned to use python script to do that... but no, i didn't know it had a serial and i did look for it! are you sure it's unique ? i actually looked for arm m0 unique id and not samd21, probably my mistake was there...

Comment: @Majenko ineed it worked, if i xxd -g0 the .bin file i can see in the end :'00000000000000003412adde' ! marked your answer as the solution but maybe you should copy the remark about the fact that there is already a uniq id for samd21...

Comment: All the AVR parts with USB have a unique ID which is intended for use as the USB serial number. I'm not sure about the SAMD21 though - check the datasheet.

Comment: From the datasheet: "Each device has a unique 128-bit serial number....The uniqueness of the serial number is guaranteed only when using all 128 bits."

Comment: Excellent. I've not worked at a low level with these chips yet, though doing so is on the cards over the next few months, as well as the E70 series. Pretty soon I will be a world authority on them :(.